IPOPT solution by Gekko in comparison to GRG algorithm used within the Excel-Solver
The aim is to compute the thermodynamically equilibrated composition of the mixture at 1000K based on Gibbs' energy of formation of the reaction products and educts (steam+C2H6 in a molar ratio of 4:1) for the ethane steam gasification reaction as following:
from gekko import GEKKO     
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
x = m.Array(m.Var,13,value=1,lb=1e-27,ub=20.0)
H2,H2O,CO,O2,CO2,CH4,C2H6,C2H4,C2H2,lamda1,lamda2,lamda3,summe= x
H2.value = 3.0
H2O.value = 1.0
CO.value = 0.5
O2.value = 0.001
CO2.value = 0.5
CH4.value = 0.1
C2H6.value = 0.000215
C2H4.value = 0.00440125
C2H2.value = 0.0041294
summe.value = 8.0
lamda1.value = 1.0
lamda2.value = 1.0
lamda3.value = 1.0
eq1 = m.Param(value=14)
eq2 = m.Param(value=4)
eq3 = m.Param(value=2)
summe = m.Var(H2 + O2 + H2O + CO + CO2 + CH4 + C2H6 + C2H4 + C2H2)
lamda2 = m.Var((-1)*m.log(H2 / summe) / 2)
lamda1 = m.Var(46.03 / 1.9872 - m.log(H2O / summe) + 2 * lamda2)
lamda3 = m.Var(47.942 / 1.9872 - m.log(CO / summe) + lamda1)
m.Equation(m.exp(-4.61 / 1.9872 - 4 * lamda2 - lamda3) * summe == CH4)
m.Equation(m.exp(-28.249 / 1.9872 - 4 * lamda2 - 2 * lamda3) * summe == C2H4)
m.Equation(m.exp(-40.604 / 1.9872 - 2 * lamda2 - 2 * lamda3) * summe == C2H2)
m.Equation(m.exp(-26.13 / 1.9872 - 6 * lamda2 - 2 * lamda3) * summe == C2H6)
m.Equation(m.exp(94.61 / 1.9872 - 2 * lamda1 - lamda3) * summe == CO2)
m.Equation(m.exp(-2 * lamda1) * summe == O2)
m.Equation(2 * CO2 + CO + 2 * O2 + H2O  == eq2)
m.Equation(4 * CH4 + 4 * C2H4 + 2 * C2H2 + 2 * H2 + 2 * H2O + 6 * C2H6  == eq1)
m.Equation(CH4 + 2 * C2H4 + 2 * C2H2 + CO2 + CO + 2 * C2H6  == eq3)
m.Minimize((summe-(H2 + O2 + H2O + CO + CO2 + CH4 + C2H6 + C2H4 + C2H2))**2)
m.options.IMODE = 3 #IPOPT
m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000
m.options.OTOL = 1e-10
m.options.RTOL = 1e-10
m.solve()
print('x: ', x)
print('Objective: ',m.options.OBJFCNVAL)


EXIT: Optimal Solution Found. 
The solution was found. 
The final value of the objective function is    81.0000000000000     

---------------------------------------------------
Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
Solution time  :   1.169999998819549E-002 sec
Objective      :    81.0000000000000     
Successful solution
---------------------------------------------------

x:  [[5.797458326] [1.202541674] [1.202541674] [1.6791020526e-21]
[0.79745832603] [1.6503662452e-22] [3.2694282596e-27] [1.1255712085e-27]
[1e-27] [2.185089969] [2.185089969] [2.185089969] [9.5605307091]]

Then using GRG as optimiser:

Both solution still differs. And interestingly, the output from a (constraint) root finder is still different, but converges at the same time:
Total number of equations:  13  
Number of implicit equations:  4  
Number of explicit equations:  9  
Solution method  CONSTRAINED  
Convergence tolerance:  1e-07  
# of iterations used:  8  

CO  1.685236
H2  5.118105
H2O  1.387357
SUM  8.899115  
C2H2  0.0041294  
C2H4  0.0044224  
C2H6  0.0092403  
CH4  0.2269213  
CO2  0.0522585  
lamda1  1.537016  
lamda2  0.2765838  
lamda3  2.53957  
O2  0.4114448  

Here is a comparison of the solutions:



Solution Vector x
GEKKO
EXCEL GRG
Root finder
GEKKO-final




H2: 1
5.797458326
5.344360712
5.118105
5.219


H2O: 2
1.202541674
1.521995663
1.387357
1.681


CO: 3
1.202541674
1.388351672
1.685236
1.581


O2: 4
1.6791020526e-21
5.82E-21
0.4114448
1e-5


CO2: 5
0.79745832603
0.544826
0.0522585
0.3693


CH4: 6
1.6503662452e-22
0.0668213
0.2269213
0.05


C2H6: 7
3.2694282596e-27
1.70E-07
0.0092403
1e-5


C2H4: 8
1.1255712085e-27
9.74E-08
0.0044224
1e-5


C2H2: 9
1e-27
3.25E-10
0.0041294
1e-5


lamda1: 10
2.185089969
24.3878385
1.537016



lamda2: 11
2.185089969
0.253110984
0.2765838



lamda3: 12
2.185089969
1.558979624
2.53957



summe: 13
9.5605307091
8.866356107
8.899115
8.90




Welcome to stack overflow. It would help a lot if you annotated the solution vector x so we can compare more easily. The best thing to do with any "optimised" solution is to feed the answer back through the set of equations it is supposed to be the solution to and see what the residual errors look like. Equations with exp(-ax) in can end up wildly inaccurate if the starting guess is just slightly wrong. BTW I wouldn't trust Excel's GRG optimiser to solve anything but toy problems accurately. I can break it on quite simple rational polynomial approximation problems without any difficulty.

@MartinBrown, thank you for the warm welcome here. I added some more about problem description and also just made the output vector x better comparable.

The variables lamda1 ,lamda2, lamda3, summe are defined twice and the equations associated with those variables are only used to initialize the second definition of the variables.
H2,H2O,CO,O2,CO2,CH4,C2H6,C2H4,C2H2,lamda1,lamda2,lamda3,summe= x
summe = m.Var(H2 + O2 + H2O + CO + CO2 + CH4 + C2H6 + C2H4 + C2H2)
lamda2 = m.Var((-1)*m.log(H2 / summe) / 2)
lamda1 = m.Var(46.03 / 1.9872 - m.log(H2O / summe) + 2 * lamda2)
lamda3 = m.Var(47.942 / 1.9872 - m.log(CO / summe) + lamda1)

Switching them to Intermediate() definitions is an easy way to fix the problem.
summe = m.Intermediate(H2 + O2 + H2O + CO + CO2 + CH4 + C2H6 + C2H4 + C2H2)
lamda2 = m.Intermediate((-1)*m.log(H2 / summe) / 2)
lamda1 = m.Intermediate(46.03 / 1.9872 - m.log(H2O / summe) + 2 * lamda2)
lamda3 = m.Intermediate(47.942 / 1.9872 - m.log(CO / summe) + lamda1)

Here is the complete script:
from gekko import GEKKO   
import numpy as np  
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
x = m.Array(m.Var,9,value=1,lb=1e-27,ub=20.0)
H2,H2O,CO,O2,CO2,CH4,C2H6,C2H4,C2H2=x
H2.value = 3.0
H2O.value = 1.0
CO.value = 0.5
O2.value = 0.001
CO2.value = 0.5
CH4.value = 0.1
C2H6.value = 0.000215
C2H4.value = 0.00440125
C2H2.value = 0.0041294
eq1 = m.Param(value=14)
eq2 = m.Param(value=4)
eq3 = m.Param(value=2)
summe = m.Intermediate(H2 + O2 + H2O + CO + CO2 + CH4 + C2H6 + C2H4 + C2H2)
lamda2 = m.Intermediate((-1)*m.log(H2 / summe) / 2)
lamda1 = m.Intermediate(46.03 / 1.9872 - m.log(H2O / summe) + 2 * lamda2)
lamda3 = m.Intermediate(47.942 / 1.9872 - m.log(CO / summe) + lamda1)
m.Equation(m.exp(-4.61 / 1.9872 - 4 * lamda2 - lamda3) * summe == CH4)
m.Equation(m.exp(-28.249 / 1.9872 - 4 * lamda2 - 2 * lamda3) * summe == C2H4)
m.Equation(m.exp(-40.604 / 1.9872 - 2 * lamda2 - 2 * lamda3) * summe == C2H2)
m.Equation(m.exp(-26.13 / 1.9872 - 6 * lamda2 - 2 * lamda3) * summe == C2H6)
m.Equation(m.exp(94.61 / 1.9872 - 2 * lamda1 - lamda3) * summe == CO2)
m.Equation(m.exp(-2 * lamda1) * summe == O2)
m.Equation(2 * CO2 + CO + 2 * O2 + H2O  == eq2)
m.Equation(4 * CH4 + 4 * C2H4 + 2 * C2H2 + 2 * H2 + 2 * H2O + 6 * C2H6  == eq1)
m.Equation(CH4 + 2 * C2H4 + 2 * C2H2 + CO2 + CO + 2 * C2H6  == eq3)
m.Minimize((summe-(H2 + O2 + H2O + CO + CO2 + CH4 + C2H6 + C2H4 + C2H2))**2)
m.options.IMODE = 3 #IPOPT
m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000
m.options.OTOL = 1e-10
m.options.RTOL = 1e-10
m.solve()
print('x: ', x)
print('Objective: ',m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
print(f'H2: {H2.value[0]}')
print(f'H2O: {H2O.value[0]}')
print(f'CO: {CO.value[0]}')
print(f'O2: {O2.value[0]}')
print(f'CO2: {CO2.value[0]}')
print(f'CH4: {CH4.value[0]}')
print(f'C2H6: {C2H6.value[0]}')
print(f'C2H4: {C2H4.value[0]}')
print(f'C2H2: {C2H2.value[0]}')

The objective value is now 0 with 0 degrees of freedom as required for root finding. The solution is:
 The solution was found.
 
 The final value of the objective function is   0.000000000000000E+000
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :   1.099999999860302E-002 sec
 Objective      :   0.000000000000000E+000
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
x:  [[5.0] [2.0] [2.0] [1.0421441742e-21] [3.9704669403e-23]
 [2.1920286233e-23] [1e-27] [1e-27] [1e-27]]
Objective:  0.0
H2: 5.0
H2O: 2.0
CO: 2.0
O2: 1.0421441742e-21
CO2: 3.9704669403e-23
CH4: 2.1920286233e-23
C2H6: 1e-27
C2H4: 1e-27
C2H2: 1e-27

This solution doesn't look quite right for the water-gas shift reaction. I had to go back and refresh my memory for the equilibrium composition of a reacting mixture containing ethane (C₂H₆) and steam (H₂O) at 1000 K.

1. Steam Reforming Reaction
The primary reaction for hydrogen production:
C2H6 + 2H2O → 2CO + 5H2


Purpose: Converts hydrocarbons into carbon monoxide (CO) and hydrogen (H₂) in the presence of steam.
Thermodynamic Effect: Highly endothermic, favored at high temperatures.


2. Water-Gas Shift Reaction
A secondary reaction between carbon monoxide and steam:
CO + H2O ↔ CO2 + H2


Purpose: Converts CO to CO₂ and produces additional H₂.
Thermodynamic Effect: Exothermic, favored at lower temperatures but occurs at equilibrium even at high temperatures.


3. Other Hydrocarbon Reactions
The system also includes the decomposition and partial oxidation of hydrocarbons:

Ethylene Formation (C₂H₄):
C2H6 → C2H4 + H2


Acetylene Formation (C₂H₂):
C2H4 → C2H2 + H2




4. Carbon Deposition
Carbon deposition can occur under certain conditions:
CO → C (solid) + CO2

or
CH4 → C (solid) + 2H2


Purpose: Represents undesirable side reactions where carbon deposits as a solid.
Thermodynamic Effect: Can occur at lower hydrogen-to-carbon or oxygen-to-carbon ratios, depending on system conditions.


Thermodynamic Modeling
The equilibrium composition is calculated by minimizing the Gibbs free energy of the system:
G = Σ (ni * (gi° + RT * ln(ni / ntotal)))

Where:

ni: Molar amount of species i.
gi°: Standard Gibbs free energy of formation for species i.
ntotal: Total moles of all species.

Constraints:

Mass balances for carbon, hydrogen, and oxygen.
Bounds on mole amounts to avoid non-physical solutions.

Here is a complete script based on these equations:
from gekko import GEKKO

# Create GEKKO model
m = GEKKO(remote=True)

# Define variables for species molar amounts
n_C2H6 = m.Var(value=1.0, lb=0, ub=1)  # Ethane
n_H2O = m.Var(value=4.0, lb=0, ub=1)   # Water
n_CO = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=0, ub=1)    # Carbon monoxide
n_CO2 = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=0, ub=1)   # Carbon dioxide
n_H2 = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=0, ub=1)    # Hydrogen
n_CH4 = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=0, ub=1)   # Methane
n_C = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=0, ub=1)     # Solid carbon
n_C2H4 = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=0, ub=1)  # Ethylene
n_C2H2 = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=0, ub=1)  # Acetylene

# Universal gas constant
R = 1.9872 # cal/(K mol)

# Gibbs free energies of formation at 1000K
gibbs_energies = {
    "C2H6": -26.13,    # Ethane
    "H2O": 46.03,      # Water (vapor)
    "CO": 47.942,      # Carbon monoxide
    "CO2": 94.61,      # Carbon dioxide
    "H2": 0.0,         # Hydrogen gas
    "CH4": -4.61,      # Methane
    "C": 0.0,          # Solid carbon
    "C2H4": -28.249,   # Ethylene
    "C2H2": -40.604    # Acetylene
}


# Define total moles
total_moles = (
    n_C2H6 + n_H2O + n_CO + n_CO2 + n_H2 + n_CH4 + n_C + n_C2H4 + n_C2H2
)

# Define the objective function (Gibbs free energy minimization)
m.Obj(
    n_C2H6 * (gibbs_energies["C2H6"]/R + m.log(n_C2H6 / total_moles + 1e-10)) +
    n_H2O * (gibbs_energies["H2O"]/R + m.log(n_H2O / total_moles + 1e-10)) +
    n_CO * (gibbs_energies["CO"]/R + m.log(n_CO / total_moles + 1e-10)) +
    n_CO2 * (gibbs_energies["CO2"]/R + m.log(n_CO2 / total_moles + 1e-10)) +
    n_H2 * (gibbs_energies["H2"]/R + m.log(n_H2 / total_moles + 1e-10)) +
    n_CH4 * (gibbs_energies["CH4"]/R + m.log(n_CH4 / total_moles + 1e-10)) +
    n_C * (gibbs_energies["C"]/R + m.log(n_C / total_moles + 1e-10)) +
    n_C2H4 * (gibbs_energies["C2H4"]/R + m.log(n_C2H4 / total_moles + 1e-10)) +
    n_C2H2 * (gibbs_energies["C2H2"]/R + m.log(n_C2H2 / total_moles + 1e-10))
)

# Mass balance constraints
# Carbon balance: 4(C2H6) = CO + CO2 + CH4 + C + C2H4 + C2H2
m.Equation(4*n_C2H6 == n_CO + n_CO2 + n_CH4 + n_C + n_C2H4 + n_C2H2)

# Oxygen balance: 3*H2O = CO + CO2
m.Equation(3*n_H2O == n_CO + n_CO2)

# Hydrogen balance with 4:1 ratio: C2H6 + 4*H2O = 2*H2 + CH4 + C2H4 + C2H2
m.Equation(4*n_H2O + n_C2H6 == 2*n_H2 + n_CH4 + n_C2H4 + n_C2H2)

# Total mole constraint for mole fraction result
m.Equation(total_moles == 1)

# Solve the model
m.solve(disp=True)

# Extract and display results
results = {
    "C2H6 (mol)": n_C2H6.value[0],
    "H2O (mol)": n_H2O.value[0],
    "CO (mol)": n_CO.value[0],
    "CO2 (mol)": n_CO2.value[0],
    "H2 (mol)": n_H2.value[0],
    "CH4 (mol)": n_CH4.value[0],
    "C (mol)": n_C.value[0],
    "C2H4 (mol)": n_C2H4.value[0],
    "C2H2 (mol)": n_C2H2.value[0]
}
[print(f'{r}: {results[r]:.4}') for r in results]

with results:
C2H6 (mol): 0.1993
H2O (mol): 0.003599
CO (mol): 0.0108
CO2 (mol): 0.0
H2 (mol): 0.0
CH4 (mol): 2.915e-09
C (mol): 0.5726
C2H4 (mol): 0.0004254
C2H2 (mol): 0.2133


thank you so much. Really very helpful n I learned a lot from this post
